# Concatenating fields in a DataFrame using Python

Tags: python

I would have thought this would be incredibly simple. I just want to concatenate 2 fields into a new one. My data looks like this

```
Time   Location
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      A
5      B
6      C
```

and I am using the following;

```
test['new'] = str(test['Time']) + str(test['Location'])
```

I want to get to;

```
Time   Location   New
1      A          1A
2      B          2B
3      C          3C
4      A          4A
5      B          5B
6      C          6C
```

I know this should be easy but it's proving more trouble some than I thought.

Comment: if one of your fields is not a string, use astype: test['Time'].astype(str) + test['Location']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it not working now ?  Because the function str() will turn your data series into a string. adding two strings will make a string, and you cannot assign a string to a data series

How to make it work : you will often need pandas or numpy internal functions to subject each element of a data series to a transformation. In this case, the function astype should work to transform the series "Time" into a string :

```
test["new"]=test['Time'].astype(str) + test['Location']
```

Comment: test['Time'].str + test['Location'] will also work, and is somewhat cleaner